# Textbox duplication issue in VB. NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, textbox, location

I'm a basic VB. NET programmer, so I still have lots of things to learn.
I've searched for an existing solution, but nothing has really satisfied my request.

Some days ago I started creating a new form application in VB. NET.
In a form I should create a list with some data, but as I need a specific user interface, I can't use some elements (e.g. DataGridView), because graphically they're terrible to manage.

At the beginning I wanted to use a database and create a DataGridView, but for the reason above I dropped this idea.
Thus, I used some textboxes, as I could handle them better for my graphical purposes. Here's the result: [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a9mC.png).

As I need to add some users, I added an 'Add' button and programmed it with this code:

```
    Dim username As New TextBox
    Dim password As New TextBox
    Dim email As New TextBox

    With username
        .Size = New Size(194, 28)
        .Font = New Font("Omnes", 12)
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        .ForeColor = Color.White
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        .Location = New Point(12, 105)
        .Enabled = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    With password
        .Size = New Size(194, 28)
        .Font = New Font("Omnes", 12)
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        .ForeColor = Color.White
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        .Location = New Point(212, 105)
        .Enabled = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    With email
        .Size = New Size(234, 28)
        .Font = New Font("Omnes", 12)
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        .ForeColor = Color.White
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        .Location = New Point(412, 105)
        .Enabled = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    AddHandler username.TextChanged, AddressOf username_TextChanged
    Me.Controls.Add(username)

    AddHandler password.TextChanged, AddressOf password_TextChanged
    Me.Controls.Add(password)

    AddHandler email.TextChanged, AddressOf email_TextChanged
    Me.Controls.Add(email)
```

What I need is to increase of 34 pixels the location on the y axis of the textboxes everytime I click on the 'Add' button (in the code that value is 105 in every textbox).
The final result should look something like this: [Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmt5H.png) (obviously in order to create this picture I manually duplicated the textboxes).
I tried every loop function, but I can't decide which one is the best in this case, and how to use it.

Can anyone kindly help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest using a `TableLayoutPanel` and just move the controls from one cell to another. Using pixels will break if the user's font resolution doesn't match your own, plus as you've seen, its a pain to do.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you're stuck.  Are you asking how to add `34` to `105`?  How to use a variable instead of a literal integer?  `"I tried every loop function"` - What does that even mean?  What did you try?

Comment: *How* is a DGV a "graphical nightmare"?  It can be gobs easier than all that code.

Comment: @David I need to add 34 to 105 for a certain number of times, so that the value increases every time I click on the 'Add' button. I tried the loop statements, such as For Each, For, While, Do While, Do Until, etc., but they gave me only problems, as I don't know which one to choose for this purpose.

Comment: @SilenoPerina: What did you try and what problems did you encounter?  If you want to perform an action in a loop then any loop construct will do the trick.  Are you just asking how to use loops?  There are VB tutorials to help with things like that.

Comment: just my 2 cents, but hard-coding a specific pixel spacing is not an ideal solution as it will not scale properly with increased DPI settings on the machine.

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ The application will not be designed to run on other PCs but mine, so this is not the part of the whole problem I'm interested in. Thank you anyway